# how to show dummy character while typing in terminal in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Using following code, I am able to hide characters while typing in terminal.

```
require 'io/console'
str =  STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
```

Though it is taking input, terminal is not showing anything while typing in terminal. I want to show dummy characters like # or *.

Like, if I am typing 'cat' , it should show '***' in terminal.
How to do it ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `str =  STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
` is more or less equivalent to `str = STDIN.getpass("password: ")`

Comment: This will be helpful too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gem called [highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) can do this:

```
require 'highline'

cli = HighLine.new
cli.ask('password:') { |q| q.echo = 'x' }
```

Comment: Run `gem install highline` firstly! @somnathsurwase

Comment: Yes. I did. Thanks for help